# Handling events of usercontrols within listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, event-handling

I have a simple usercontrol which raises an event on button click

```
Public Class UcPaymentCheque
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Event OnCancelClick()

    Private Sub btnCancelPayment_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancelPayment.Click
        RaiseEvent OnCancelClick()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This usercontrol is used within a listview

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwNonTpProducts" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemPlaceholder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <TPCustomControl:UcPaymentCheque ID="UcTPPaymentCheque" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

which is databound on page load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack Then

    Else
        BuildPage()
    End If
End Sub
```

At what point should add the handler? I have fiddled with the ondatabound event like so;

```
Private Sub lvwNonTpProducts_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvwNonTpProducts.ItemDataBound
    Dim UcTPPaymentCheque = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("UcTPPaymentCheque"), UcPaymentCheque)
    AddHandler UcTPPaymentCheque.OnCancelClick, AddressOf OnCancelClick
End Sub
```

but this does not work and am guess at a databound issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out my response to a similar question here:  [creating and listening for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096396/creating-and-listening-for-events/15097411#comment21242785_15097411)

Essentially, you want a user control to raise its own event, like this:

```
Partial Class myControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Public Event MyEvent As EventHandler

    'your button click event
    Protected Sub bnt_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      'do stuff
      'now raise the event
       RaiseEvent MyEvent (Me, New EventArgs)
    end sub
end class
```

In this example, I raise the event when the user clicks a button within the user control.  You can easily raise the event anywhere, such as when the control loads, using a timer, whatever.

Then, in the main page, you want to and an event handler to the user control, like this:

```
<mc:myControlrunat="server" ID="myControl1" OnMyEvent="myControl_MyEvent"  />
```

Now, in the code behind, you can add the event, like this:

```
Protected Sub myControl_MyEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
 'do stuff 
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the handler in the declaration of the user control in the listview, using `OnCancelClick`, as follows:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwNonTpProducts" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemPlaceholder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <TPCustomControl:UcPaymentCheque ID="UcTPPaymentCheque" runat="server" Visible="false" OnCancelClick="UcTPPaymentCheque_OnCancelClick" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Where `UcTPPaymentCheque_OnCancelClick` is the function you should use to handle the event, in the control that contains the listview.