# Validation check for controls inside UserControl inside a Repearter on a Page

Tags: validation, user-controls, ascx

I have a UserControl say - GiveIdentity.ascx (it has 2 TextBox fields SSN and DOB)

I have another UserControl say - GiveIdentityList.ascx (basically this is a repeater rendering say 3 instances of GiveIdentity UserControl)

Now I have this GiveIdentityList UserControl on say Default.aspx page.

I want to ipliment a 'IsValid' property or method.. on the GiveIdentity.ascx control itself... so that it would retrun whether all textbox fields on that particular control are valid or not... (remember I don't wanna user Page.Validators() or something on the Default.aspx page) - I want the UserControls which are inside another UserControls which is a repeater - to expose the IsValid property - suggesting that all text and date controls inside itself are valid or not....

I appreciate your help... Thanks

Comment: sorry forgot to mention - the 2 TextBox fields on the GiveIdentity.ascx UserControl has a 'Required Field Validator' on them

Comment: Where are you having difficulty?  Do you just need to know how to create a public method?  or how to create events?

Comment: I want to know how I can check whether the two TextBox fields (having isrequired validator) are valid or not... inside the UserControl (GiveIdentity.ascx) itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose a public method in your user control to any page that uses the control.  You should also add an event to alert the parent pages if the state changes.  Adding these methods are easy enough:

```
Partial Class user_controls_myControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   End sub

   Public Function isValid() as boolean

      if(me.checkbox1.text<>"" andalso me.checkbox2.text<>"") then
           return true
      else
           return false
      end if 
   End sub
end Class
```

Now, in your ASPX page that holds all of these controls, you can check that specific function to make sure they are valid.  For instance, if you have a user control called giveIdentity1, you'll want to iterate over the repeater and cast an object to your user control type.  You can then check the isValid function like this:

```
dim getBool as boolean 
getBool = me.giveIdentity1.isValid
```

If you need help iterating over the repeater, let me know

You can also create your own server events to register changes.  You can read a post to a similar topic I responded to here:  [Handling events of usercontrols within listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086283/handling-events-of-usercontrols-within-listview/15136554#15136554)

If this does not answer your question, let me know.

Comment: I have done the same implimentation... however where I am stuck is... the section where you have mention.... 'check text boxes here... how do I get each 'TextBox' validor that only belongs to that 'GiveIdentity.ascx' control... if I user 'foreach(IValidator vl in Page.Validators).... its getting all the validators for all controls in the page... any suggests ?

Comment: AS far As i know, the scope of the function isValid should only look at the text boxes that belong to its individual control.  Your aspx page that holds all of these controls would then look at that function to make sure it is set to "True".  I'll expand my answer to add that part.  let me know if that is what you want

Comment: Yes.. thats exactly what I am looking for... but I want the code that is inside the IsValid() function (the code that would basically check the 2 TextBox's validity - inside the Control itself)... Thanks for your help...

Comment: Well, I don't know what you would consider valid?  The code I have put in the isValid function checks to make sure that two fields are filled in.  What were you looking for?